# Where can I modify Chrome bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I want to code an extension that modifies your bookmarks in Google Chrome. For example, it should expand different sub-sites (e.g. reddit subreddits) when hovering over a bookmark.

Where do I find the bookmark function, though? Like the part that says for example "when hovering over an icon, background goes grey". I'd have to modify exactly those parts.

Comment: There's no such function that says "when hovering over an icon, background goes grey". You'll need to implement everything you need using JavaScript, DOM, CSS, and chrome.bookmarks API, see the documentation and examples and inspect the existing extensions.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are referring to, a simple CSS style modification will achieve. To implement an extension into chrome, you will want to start here:

[Google Chrome Extension Development](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions)

Some resources for you:

[Developer Guide](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/devguide) - this contains all the extensible chrome APIs

[chrome.bookmarks API](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks) - this is the API that will interact with and manipulate bookmarks

There are also some resources out there that are helpful for learning how to create a chrome extension. A good starting point may be this:

[How to create and publish a chrome extension in 20 minutes](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-and-publish-a-chrome-extension-in-20-minutes-6dc8395d7153)